# Function return type ambiguity on release and debug versions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I have two projects on one solution;  say *Project1* and *Project2*. Project1 includes only abstarct classes and their implementations, and it is added as a referance to Project2. One of the functions, *Connect()* in *Class1* in Project1 is defined as follows;

```
 public bool Connect() { ...TCP connection code }
```

On Project2, Connect function of *Object1* is called as;

```
 if (carlValentin.Connect() != false) {...}
```

Visual Studio 2010 is used as IDE.
Here comes the oddness. When I choose *Debug* as configuration, everything goes fine, compilation is done and application runs. However, when I switch the configuration to *Release*, I get the following function return type error;
`Operator != cannot be applied to the operands of type void and bool`.

Project1 does not include any other overloaded methods for Connect function. As mentioned, Project2 is dependent into Project1. I suspect if it is a problem with the changes I made, since previous definition of Connect had void as return type. But I'm pretty sure that project build order is configured so that Project1 is compiled first and then Project2 is built.

Comment: Rebuild all your projects.

Comment: Have you tried doing a full rebuild of the solution now that you're in release mode?

Comment: Just tried it, still the same.

Comment: I assume there's no `#if DEBUG` or `[Conditional("DEBUG")]` in play here? (or indeed, the same with `RELEASE` rather than `DEBUG`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll say that the list of what is compiled in the various Debug/Release mode got broken. Go to Build->Configuration Manager, select all the various combinations of Debug/Release mode and platforms and check that all the various `Build` checkboxes are checked.

Comment: Yes, that worked. I have checked Build checkbox for Release configuration of Project1. However, it is not thicked in Debug mode but everything goes fine.Anyways, it is solved but i am still curious why I did not need to change anything in Debug mode but in Release mode.

Comment: @MCG Because at a certain point the debug was forced-built and then it remained in the debug folder. If you delete the debug folder you'll see the same problem.